# Green's function for the Klein-Gordon operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, klein-gordon-equation, propagator

I'm not very sure I get the right way of verifying Feynman's propagator is indeed the Green's function for KG operator. The propagator is

$$\Delta_F(x-y)=\int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{ie^{ip\cdot(x-y)}}{p^2-m^2}.$$

You act the KG operator on it,

$$(\partial_t^2-\nabla^2+m^2) \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{ie^{ip\cdot(x-y)}}{p^2-m^2} .$$

$\partial_t$ has no impact on the integral, so it just passes over. Then the Laplacian pulls out a factor $(ip)^2=-p^2$. So the operator multiplies the integral by $(-p^2+m^2)$ which cancels with the denominator in integrand, and the whole just becomes a Dirac delta function.

Comment: The integral runs over a 4-dimensional momentum. In other words, it includes the temporal component. So the $(x-y)$ in the exponent is a 4-vector and therefore must include $t$ as well. Other than that you're right. The result should be a Dirac delta.